# Доработать функцию PHP?

Tags: php

Я только начинаю осваивать PHP.
Код, которым я пользуюсь:

```
<?php
$file = 'result.txt';
$long_url = urlencode('mylink.com');
$api_token = '0123456789';
$api_url = "https://mysite.com/api?api={$api_token}&url={$long_url}";
$result = file_get_contents($api_url);
if( $result ){
 echo $result;
}
file_put_contents($file, $long_url . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
file_put_contents($file, $result . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
fclose($file);
sleep(1);
?>
```

Вроде бы работает исправно.
Но мне необходимо ссылку **mylink.com** брать из отдельного файла **mylink.txt**.
Размер файла примерно 10-30 мб.

В нём список ссылок, каждая в отдельной строке. Надо, чтобы по очереди бралась одна ссылка, обрабатывалась с помощью функции выше и результат записывался в файл **result.txt**.

Есть такой вариант чтения файла:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('mylink.txt', 'r');
while (!feof($file)) {
    echo fgets($file);
    echo '<br>';
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

Но как соединить эти функции, я без понятия.

В результате должно произойти следующее:

1. прочтена ссылка из файла **mylink.txt**
2. ссылка обработана с помощью **$api_url**
3. результат записан в файл **result.txt** в такой последовательности (в одной строке записывается **$long_url**, в следующей строке записывается **$result**
4. Далее выполняется задержка 1 сек.
5. Цикл продолжается, до тех пор, пока файл **mylink.txt** полностью не будет прочитан.

**Пожалуйста, помогите доработать код.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен!
Спасибо [@Алексей-Р](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/519463/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A0) за помощь!

Нужно удалить `fclose($file);` и в конце поставить `fseek($file, 0);`

```
<?php
function handle_url($url) {
    $file = 'result.txt';
    $long_url = urlencode($url);
    $api_token = '0123456789';
    $api_url = "https://mysite.com/api?api={$api_token}&url={$long_url}";
    $result = file_get_contents($api_url);
    if ($result) {
        echo $result;
    }
    file_put_contents($file, $long_url . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents($file, $result . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    sleep(1);
}
$file = fopen('mylink.txt', 'r');
if ($file) {
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        handle_url($line);
    }
    fseek($file, 0);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

В общих чертах так: создаете функцию для обработки, в т.ч. сохранения ulr-ов, например, `handle_url()`. Далее - организуете цикл чтения данных из файла и каждую строку передаете в `handle_url()`.
Не тестировал.

```
<?php
function handle_url($url){
    $file = 'result.txt';
    $long_url = urlencode($url);
    $api_token = '0123456789';
    $api_url = "https://mysite.com/api?api={$api_token}&url={$long_url}";
    $result = file_get_contents($api_url);
    if( $result ){
        echo $result;
    }
    file_put_contents($file, $long_url . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    file_put_contents($file, $result . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    fclose($file);
    sleep(1);
}

$file = fopen('mylink.txt', 'r');
if ($file){
    while (!feof($file)) {
        handle_url(fgets($file));
    }
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Уже на один шаг ближе к решению. Да, ссылка берется из файла но только первая. Скрипт нормально записывает результат в файл. И все. Скрипт останавливается. Если его повторно запустить, происходит все тоже самое - только ссылка из первой строки читается, обрабатывается и записывается.

Comment: А дальше - отлаживайте код. Например, [так](https://epsiloncool.ru/programmirovanie/php/prostoj-sposob-otladki-programm-na-php).

Comment: Нужно удалить fclose($file); и в конце поставить fseek($file, 0);